# ¿Como poner dos clases en Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, nextjs, next

Estoy empezando con nextjs y me di cuenta que se genera un gran problema al tratar de poner dos clases diferentes en una misma etiqueta HTML, quiero poner dos clases haciendo uso del **'.module.css'**. Para esto cree una carpeta por fuera de la carpeta **src/app** llamada **styles**, dentro de la carpeta **styles** hay un archivo llamado **index.module.css** que contiene lo siguiente:

```
 .title__omellete{
    font-size: 35px;
}
```

mientras que en la pagina principal tengo esto:

```
import styles from '../../styles/index.module.css'
import { Young_Serif } from "next/font/google";

const young_serif = Young_Serif({
  weight:'400',
  subsets:['latin'],
  display:'swap',
  style:'normal',
})

const Index = () => {
  return (<>
      <h1 className={`${young_serif.className} ${styles.title__omellete}`}>Simple Ommellete Recipe</h1></>)}
```

La etiqueta  tiene dos clases, (tengo entendido que a nivel sintáctico la forma de poner dos clases en una etiqueta esta bien, en teoria: **className={`${young_serif.className} ${styles.title__omellete}`}** a pesar de que todo esta bien a nivel sintáctico, los efectos de CSS no funcionan.

Cuando saco el .modulo.css y lo paso dentro de la carpeta src/app como un archivo normal junto con las otros componentes e importarlo de forma correspondiente: **import './index.css'** el CSS funciona. En el navegador no arroja un error que haga referencia a el porque no me agarra el css, salvo esto (que no tiene nada que ver ya que es otro problema):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Porque no funciona esto?, ¿que hago mal?

En la explicación puse lo esencial para que puedan entender el problema, dejo capturas por si necesitan ver el código:

estructura de carpetas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

contenido de pagina principal **LINEA 19**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

contenido de css:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta que el código siempre este como texto y formateado como código con las herramientas del sitio. He probado lo mismo que estas intentando con NextJS y me funciona perfectamente... agregaste la etiqueta react-native a la pregunta, estas seguro que puede usarse NextJS con React Native? y que los módulos CSS siguen funcionando usando NextJS de esa manera?

Comment: Hola buenas, tenias razon, resetie el servidor y funciono, muchas gracias